# Single Integer Color Input: What Color Space? How to enter Greyscale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a set of maps in R and am looking to color my points, but I am unsure what color space I inputed. My code is as follows:

```
library("ggplot2")
library("sf")
library("rnaturalearth")
library("rnaturalearthdata")
library("maps")

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
states <- st_as_sf(map("state", plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
states <- cbind(states, st_coordinates(st_centroid(states)))

ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = states, fill = "cornsilk") + 
  geom_path(data = observationsByReceiver, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude)) +
  geom_point(data = observationsByReceiver, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), size = 2, color = 2)
```

There are a couple more lines, but they are purely stylistic.

My questions is what color space is it when I write "color = 2"? I'm looking to create a grey scale gradient for my points and thought this might be the way to input gray scale, but it comes out as red. So what space am I in? And how do I input grey scale?

Thank you.

Comment: probably base R colors. You can use `+ scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greys")`

Comment: For a grayscale gradient, the `grDevices` package (comes with R) has a function `gray.colors`, which can give you a palette of equi-distant gray colours. `imager` seems to have a function `grayscale` as well.

Comment: @Oliver you're right, the brewer palette gives a discrete scale, not a gradient. the OP may also want to look into scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Greys"), which is extrapolating the grey brewer palette to continuous

Comment: Indeed @Tjebo, and commonly there's a thought behind pre-defined palettes such as helping specific types of colourblindness, which might be better mitigated by non-equi-distant palettes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your second question:
Looking into `?palette`:

> View or manipulate the color palette which is used when col= has a numeric index (etc...)

Interestingly, ggplot2 doesn't change this after setting the palette.

**update**

[ggplot2 maintainer Thomas Lin Pedersen on this issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4106#issuecomment-652058800):

> This is ... a known result of using farver for colour conversion.

```r
library(ggplot2)

palette()
#> [1] "black"   "#DF536B" "#61D04F" "#2297E6" "#28E2E5" "#CD0BBC" "#F5C710"
#> [8] "gray62"
plot(1:8, col = 1:8, pch = 16)
```

[image]

```r
#change the palette to "Reds"
palette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(8, "Reds"))
plot(1:8, col = 1:8, pch = 16)
```

[image]

```r
# ggplot2 does not change, still the original palette ... 
# (I guess it does not scope for the palette in the global environment)
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:8, y = 1), aes(x,y, color = x)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'll illustrate with the iris dataset, as I don't have the packages you state and I'm not looking to download these at the moment.

In general there are 2 scenarios: 1 for categorical variables and 1 for continuous variables.

### Categorical

The simplest case is if you want all points in the same layer to have the same colour. You can then simply add the colour as argument to the layer.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.2

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(color = "blue")
```

[image]

A second case occurs when you want to map your aesthetic to a (colour) scale, which is more common if you want to have finer control over the looks of your point. By default it sort of chooses colours along a rainbow for you.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species))
```

[image]

Lastly, you can control the mapped colour via a scale. For you example, this is a greyscale that would fit.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) +
  scale_colour_brewer(palette = "Greys")
```

[image]

### Continuous

Continuous values are most often mapped to a scale. By default it chooses a blue palette for you.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Petal.Width))
```

[image]

But again, you can control the gradient via the scale too.

```r
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Petal.Width)) +
  scale_colour_distiller(palette = "Greys")
```

[image]

As an aside, the same thing applies to fills but they colour different parts of graphical objects.